# Get substring between two special characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, substring

Current

```
Str = 'T1##12##30####T2##10##40;'
```

Desired Output for T1

```
double1 =  12
double2 =  30
```

Desired Output for T2

```
double1 = 10
double2 = 40
```

Comment: Try `var arr = Str.split('##')` see where that takes you

Comment: Use regular expressions with `RegExp`. Try it and show us your progress with it.

Answer (score 2):

[`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) is what you are looking for

```js
const str = 'T1##12##30####T2##10##40;'

for (const [_, T1, T2] of str.matchAll(/T\d##(\d+)##(\d+)/g)) {
  console.log(T1, T2)
}
```

```html
Desired Output for T1

double1 =  12
double2 =  30
Desired Output for T1

double1 = 10
double2 = 40
```